# jquery plugin to quickly layout form?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a complex form to layout.Assume screen is equally divided into two parts vertically .left segment store form and right segment store grids. I am very bad at CSS. I want a jquery plugin which can quickly layout form for me. Is there anything which can help?I am using jquery validation engine for validation purpose and methivin splitter plugin to separate header,body and fotter. The body part contains this form which is an iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this. In fact, I'd caution against using JavaScript for layout.

Instead, try a CSS framework like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html). Bootstrap, for example, has form-formatting facilities: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Comment: if I use bootstrap then my other jquery plugin may gets impacted right? I have other jquery plugins used in the project..Bootstrap comes with their own js codes which is I think made with jquery..let me know ur view

Comment: You can choose to download just the CSS with the Customize page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html. Just deselect all the items under "JS Components" and "Select jQuery Plugins".